# Error on sql statement

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT AVG(totalled) as mySum , `id` 
FROM (
        SELECT totalled,id 
        FROM `figure` 
        where `userid`='".$userid."' 
        ORDER BY id DESC 
        LIMIT 4
    ) t1
```

I've created this statement but the error I am getting is:
Static analysis:

3 errors were found during analysis.

> An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 42)
>   Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 42)
>   This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "SELECT" at position 43)
>   SQL query: Documentation

```
SELECT AVG(totalled) as mySum , `id` 
FROM (
        SELECT totalled,id 
        FROM `figure` 
        where `userid`='".$userid."' 
        ORDER BY id DESC 
        LIMIT 4
    ) t1
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 't1.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

What would I have to do to fix this problem.

[image: Table Image]

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: What would be the best thing to do RiggsFolly?

Comment: Look up `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` in the MYSQL Manual

Comment: why give alias t1, even if given  use AVG(t1.totalled) as mySum , `t1.id`

Answer (score 0):

Yuo have a column (id) that is not in group by so the db engine raise an error.  this happen starting from mysql 5.7

```
SELECT AVG(totalled) as mySum , `id` 
FROM (
    SELECT totalled,id 
    FROM `figure` 
    where `userid`='".$userid."' 
    ORDER BY id DESC 
    LIMIT 4
 ) t1
group by `id`
```